# What did I do differently?

Tags: discussion

In the last couple weeks I've posted two questions about the specific semantics of accessing memory in C. In neither case was I facing a specific problem, so an MCVE isn't really appropriate in either case. I am just exploring and researching this topic for my own interests for the moment.

- [Do C standards specify how far the carry propagates when incrementing a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848935/do-c-standards-specify-how-far-the-carry-propagates-when-incrementing-a-pointer)
- [How do C compilers provide access to several memories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095583/how-do-c-compilers-provide-access-to-several-memories)

Thing is, one question was much better received than the other! That second question was put on hold and received a down vote, but the first one wasn't.

I'm asking so that I can ask better questions in the future: what did I do differently?

Comment: The first one asks about the C standard -> Exactly one correct answer. The second one asks about a compiler backend detail without saying which compiler -> Infinite number of possible answers (one for each compiler out there).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The questions are very different.

The one question is "what does the spec say". Since the spec can only say one thing, this has one and only one very specific answer (although there can be multiple versions of this answer, where people focus on different parts or add different additional information).

The other one seems like it's about all C compilers and all architectures, and one might even be able to dedicate a few chapters of a book to just covering one specific way of doing it (I suspect, but I'm not sure). Either of those things by themselves would make the question too broad (there would be too many possible answers, or they would be too long). I wouldn't be able to tell you whether there's a version of that question that's on topic though.